# Where can I find a web-based interactive org chart API?

Tags: charts, svg, visualization, organization

I'm looking to build an interactive web-based org chart for a large organization.  I somewhat like the interface at ancestry.com where you can hover over people and pan/zoom around and click on different nodes to make them the root.

Ideally, I'd like it if people could belong to multiple organizational entities like committees, working groups, etc.  In other words the API should support graphs in general, not just trees.

I'd like to be able to visually explode each organizational substructure into substituents by clicking on it, with a nice animation of the employees ballooning or spilling out so you can really interactively drill down through the organization.

I found http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html but it looks a bit rudimentary.

I know there are desktop tools like OrgPlus and Visio that can build static charts but I'm really looking for a free, web-based API with open standards-based output like SVG or HTML5 Canvas elements rather than Flash or some proprietary output.  Something I can embed into a custom web application and style myself.  Something interactive.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is this one for asp.net but I have only ever added it to my bookmarks so I can't vouch for how standards compliant it is:

- http://www.orgchartcomponent.com/

Something you should also consider when you are looking in to this is your charting requirements. Many org charts only support a single top node. If you wanted to map a family tree for example then this might not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Check my solution on github: [OrgChart.svg](https://github.com/BrightShadow/orgchart.svg) This is a modern full SVG orgchart with support of  custom styling, tip-over / stacking possibility in the best known form. I would be very happy if it helps someone. It is based on snap.svg.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the SpaceTree API from the Javascript InfoVis Toolkit to build my org chart:

http://philogb.github.com/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Visualizations/Spacetree-js.html

Answer (score 0):

I've had a go at building this in d3.js.  It was originally built for data pulled from Yammer but now it will work with any csv - like [this](https://github.com/RobinL/d3_orgchart_yammer/blob/3bbc43a48b275e8920fa0b8a2b370c58d75d1f06/website/data/random_data_flat_file.csv) one.

[Here's](https://github.com/RobinL/d3_orgchart_yammer) the repo and [here's](http://robinl.github.io/d3_orgchart_yammer/website/) a demo.  You will need to know a little html/javascript to customise it for your application.

Comment: It is impressive. Which license is applied?

Comment: MIT, see licence.txt in the repo.